# Jenkins: commit email -> username mapping with Github OAuth plugin

Tags: jenkins

After updating the Jenkins email-ext plugin to 2.57.1, which has a security fix to avoid sending emails to non-Jenkins users, I'm seeing messages like this in build logs:

`Not sending mail to user <user>@<domain> with no permission to view <project> #3`

The Jenkins server is using the Github OAuth plugin for authentication and the role-based access control plugin for authorization (based on Github teams). The user definitely has permission because I could see the message in the build log on his machine with him logged in.

My guess is that Jenkins isn't correctly mapping the email address from the git commit to the user created by the Github OAuth plugin. How do I make that work? I've checked that the email address in the commit matches the email address shown when the user selects to configure his account in Jenkins.